# Поиск дочернего элемента в jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

Есть вот такой блок для перелистывания "страниц" таблицы. Когда их очень много.

```
<div id="pages">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="three wide column">
            <div class="ui small right labeled input fluid">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="ui basic label">из 125</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="ui small basic icon buttons">
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="arrow left icon"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="arrow right icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Пытаюсь сделать его повторно используемым. В метод для настройки событий кнопок и поля ввода, передаю id и функцию события. И тут начинаются странности:

`$("#pages")` - находит элемент

```
var node = $("#pages");
node.find("input");
```

не находит элемент

```
var node = $("#pages");
node.find("button.ui.button").has("i.arrow.left.icon");
```

не находит элемент

**UPD**

По поводу динамики, вот что забыл упомянуть: `<div id="pages">` - это vue объект, у него есть условие, если кол-во страниц больше 10ти, показывать в качестве содержимого `<div class="ui grid">`, если меньше - другое. И самое странное, в блоке v-if поиск работает, а в v-else - нет.

Метод по привязке событий к кнопкам вызывается так, чтобы учитывать внесенные изменения:

```
vuePages.$nextTick(function(){initInput(jqSelector, event);});
```

При этом получить input из $("#pages") на чистом js получилось без проблем

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
    console.log("First:");
    var node = $("#pages");
    console.log(node.find("button.ui.button").has("i.arrow.left.icon").length);
    
    console.log("Second:");
    console.log($("#pages").find("button.ui.button").has("i.arrow.left.icon").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pages">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="three wide column">
            <div class="ui small right labeled input fluid">
                <input type="text">
                <div class="ui basic label">из 125</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="ui small basic icon buttons">
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="arrow left icon"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="ui button">
                    <i class="arrow right icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если просто смотреть на статический код, то все работает, как видите на примере.

Скорее всего ваша страница динамически что-то заменяет, дорисовывает или модифицирует что-то, и вы в динамическом DOM уже не находите элементы, который видели в статическом стартовом варианте кода.

Используйте любой отладчик, есть во всех современных браузерах, F12 по умолчанию, и посмотрите на элементы Инспектором. Он покажет именно динамическое состояние.

Comment: Мой косяк. Добавил информацию по динамике.

Comment: Может быть стоит вынести навигацию за DOM-контейнер, который динамически изменяется? Тогда не придется перепривязывать, и не надо будет мучится с динамикой.

Comment: У меня есть вариант для крайнего случая( последняя строка). Еще теплится надежда сделать все это без перебора элементов вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Вот делаю лог просто на вашем коде, и все находит так как нужно.

Возможно что вы просто не сохранили найденные элементы в какой нибудь переменной.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var node = $("#pages");
  var tmp = node.find("input");
  console.log(tmp);
  
  tmp = node.find("button.ui.button").has("i.arrow.left.icon");
  
  console.log(tmp);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pages">
  <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="three wide column">
          <div class="ui small right labeled input fluid">
              <input type="text">
              <div class="ui basic label">из 125</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
          <div class="ui small basic icon buttons">
              <button class="ui button">
                  <i class="arrow left icon"></i>
              </button>
              <button class="ui button">
                  <i class="arrow right icon"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```